# Having a hard proving $\{ t_i > 0 \mid \sum t_i = 1\}$ is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $S = \{ (t_0, ..., t_n) \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid \forall i, t_i >0, \sum t_i = 1\}$. Is the set $S$ closed or open or neither ?

I think the set $S$ is closed, yet it's hard for me to prove it.Here is my try : 
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+2} :  (t_0,...,t_n) \mapsto (t_0,t_1,...,t_n, \sum t_i)$. Then since we know that the $t_i$ can't be equal to $1$ since it would imply that the other $t_i$ are $0$, we have that :

$$S = f^{-1}(]0,1[, ..., ]0,1[, \{1\})$$

Yet here I I think I can't conclude since $(]0,1[, ..., \{1\})$ is not open and not closed...

Thank you !

Comment: Open in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$ or in the hyperplane cut out by $\sum t_i=1$?

Comment: @kimchilover in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$

Comment: Then @angryavian's answer below covers it.

Comment: @kimchilover the thing is that it's with the "check whether all points in the neighboorhood sastisfy the constraint $S$" that I am struggeling with...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for checking if $S$ is closed or not: consider the point $(1-\frac{1}{k}, \frac{1}{kn}, \ldots, \frac{1}{kn}) \in S$ and take $k \to \infty$.

Hint for checking if $S$ is open or not: pick a point of $S$ and consider any neighborhood of it. Do all points of this neighborhood satisfy the constraints defining $S$?

Comment: Thank you. I see that $S$ is not closed since your sequence converges to $(1,0,0,0..)$ which is not in $S$. Yet can you elaborate on your second point ? If I take an open ball $B(s,\epsilon)$ where $s \in S$, then if I take a point $v \in B(s,\epsilon)$ I don't see how to calculate $ \|v\|$...

Comment: @dghkgfzyukz If $s\in S$, then $(s_0+\epsilon/2,s1,\dots,s_n)\in B(s,\epsilon)$, but it does not belong to $S$ as you can see.